# microdata & meta element

Tags: html, microdata

I want to use microdata on my prodcuts page

For example:

```
Prix: <span itemprop="price">25</span>
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
```

If all my products are in euros on my page, can i add this meta in the **html head section** ?
It'll be more clean !

It's the same problem with the availability meta tag, all my products are new, i would like to add the meta tag in my head section and not in all my products div ...

Comment: you have microdata and microformats confused. itemprop is microdata

Comment: I changed the question accordingly (it is now mentioning "microdata" instead of "microformats").

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just give your `<meta>` element an `id`, and ensure that each `itemscope` has an `itemref` attribute that includes the `id` in its list.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a lot of backend processing code done already, you may want to go the HTML5 data attribute route. http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

As a plus, this is completely valid HTML5.